# During migrating tool from windows to linux lxml error

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I have developed a tool in python 2.7 that take **xsd** file as input ,
 and give the process data into a test file
During processing the **xsd** file I used **lxml**, I am unable to resolve this sort of error.

```
 AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'iterdescendants'
```

I don`t know what wrong with the **lxml lib**.

I want to know is there any **lxml** Linux compatible version for python 2.7 
I have imported in the file like below:

```
try:
    from lxml import etree
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
```

I have imported only in file , and sending the element tree pointer to process the the element into another file , 
it is OK in the declared file , giving error in another file only.

the code throw the error is :

```
for tdocNode in lincFileRootNode:
    rootNode =  tdocNode.getroot()
    lchildren = rootNode.getchildren()
    for elt in lchildren:
        if 'complex' == elt.tag:
            if 'name' in  elt.attrib:
                if 'element' == item.tag:
                    if 'type' in item.attrib:
                        if elt.attrib['name'] == item.attrib['type']:
                            for key in elt.iterdescendants(tag='element'):
                                bIsElemTypeSimple = false
                                bIsElemTypeSimple = process_elementtype(key, lincFileRootNode)
```

where :

```
lincFileRootNode  --> is list that containe the xsd file pointer to be processed
```

the error thrown is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1210, in <module>
    iret = xsd2dic_main()
  File "run.py", line 71, in xsd2dic_main
    iRet = yxsdtodic()
  File "run.py", line 352, in yxsdtodic
    iret = process_xsdfile(sXsdPath)
  File "run.py", line 485, in xsdfile
    sRet = process_dic_elementtype(item,lincFileRootNode)
  File "run.py", line 817, in process_dic_elementtype
    for key in elt.iterdescendants(tag='element'):
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'iterdescendants'
```

i tired in the both the cases :

1:writing all code in a same file
 2:writing different files

still i am getting the same error

Comment: any other information required to resolve the problem please let me know

Comment: Since the `import` isn't causing the error, it would be best to remove it from the question. Instead, determine which import is actually being used, indicate that in the question, and show us the code that's throwing the error. It would be very, very helpful if you can create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). (You might even figure it out yourself in the process.)

Comment: i have updated the scenario and code snipest

Comment: when i am printing 'elt' the its printing

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a guess, but look into it.

You appear to be calling [`iterdescendants`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#iterdescendants) from `lxml`'s implementation of the `Element` type. However, if `lxml` fails to import, you fall back on Python's built in `xml` library instead. But it's implementation of [`Element`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) doesn't have an `iterdescendants` methods of any kind. In other words, the two implementations have different public APIs. Add some `print` statements to see which library you're importing and do some additionally checking to see exactly what `type` `elt` is. If you want to be able to fall back on Python's built in `xml`, you'll need to structure your code to accommodate the different APIs.

Comment: when printing 'elt' : <Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType' at 0xb7c4526c>

Comment: how can i print which library it is using

Comment: @AzamKhan You can tell which import is being used by putting `print` statements inside your try/except. You are swallowing an exception. Unless you put some code to notify someone in there, you have no idea what is happening. This is why silently swallowing exceptions is bad.

Comment: i am not clear what you are saying ,now i am just using **import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree** still i am not getting what you want

Comment: I hadn't realized you eliminated the `lxml` import; I don't see where you mentioned it. If that's correct, the error is because this method doesn't exist in the `xml` API. When you loop over `lchildren`, it contains `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` objects, and those objects don't have an `iterdescendants` method, as I mentioned in my answer. If you want to use `xml.etree`, you have to rewrite your code to use its methods.

Comment: instead changing the code , what we can do in linux env to using th lxml library

Comment: That depends on your system configuration. I couldn't even tell you if the prerequisites are installed. If you want to do that, you have to find out why `import lxml` isn't working, starting with what exception it's throwing.